# Targeting only one class with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

[My website here](http://spellbindersspeakers.org/febnew/speakers) I'm creating for a friend is giving me issues with the input[type="button"]. I only a specific style to be applied to the button in the sidebar ONLY. However no matter what I do it effects all buttons.

```
#sidebar.widget-wrap input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How do I make it only effect the go button in the sidebar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must duplicate `#sidebar.widget-wrap`:

```css
#sidebar.widget-wrap input[type="button"], 
#sidebar.widget-wrap input[type="submit"] {
}
```

Otherwise your selector would result in every `input[type="button"]` that is inside `#sidebar.widget-wrap` **and** every `input[type="submit"]`.

The comma has no special meaning, it only combines two (or more) selectors. The result will always be the same if you use two separate selectors instead of the combined one:

```css
div a, div span { color: yellow }
/* is the same as */
div a { color: yellow }
div span { color: yellow }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer kapa, sorry it's taken me so long to reply. I've done that but it still does not work. I've even specified it as being important but no luck. Any reason?

Comment: @kia4567 It works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B3jdE/ I took a quick look on your site, and it seems you have no `#sidebar.widget-wrap` element (an element that has the id `sidebar` and has a class `widget-wrap`). Seems like `#sidebar .widget-wrap` could help. Try to isolate the problem.